# Git add to working directory assume-unchanged files

Tags: git, github

Git version 1.8.1.2.

I have made all files in my directory have the `assume-unchanged` bit set. My goal is to push a fresh commit with all files as new/modified.
When I run `git ls-files -v` it returns the whole list of files I want to commit and push. They are listed like this:

```
h .gitignore
h Gemfile
h Gemfile.lock
h README.rdoc ...etc...
```

I tried all the git add cmds I could find, `git add .` , `git add -A`. I have tried a `git update-index --really-refresh` and other refresh cmds. But every time I run `git status` it

```
returns # On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

What does the `h` mean? How do I add these files? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You paused the change tracking for all those files with this command

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged
```

You didn't tell why you did that in the first place. It's quite an unusual thing to do (not saying it does't have it's use cases!)

To activate the change tracking again you have to use this command:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged
```